# Testing an XQuery Transformation

Tags: oracle, service, xquery, bus

I'm using Workshop for Weblogic and I'm testing an XQuery Transformation.
Both MFL and XSD are valid. But the XQuery doesn't seem to work... it gives me this error:

Error occurred while executing XQuery: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(Ljava/io/Reader;)Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, weblogic/xml/query/parsers/StAXCursorAdaptor, and the class loader (instance of ) for resolved class, javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader used in the signature

Have you ever seen this before? How can I solve this please?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue already? I don't know the solution, but it could be a CLASSPATH issue. Try starting workshop.exe from command line after clearing CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall workshop with default `JRockit`, or what is much faster just edit `workshop.ini` and change `-vm` parameter value from Sun/Oracle JDK to JRockit SDK which can be found in weblogic directory.